# I want to integrate Auth0 in my frontend fetched from backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, auth0

I am creating a full-stack app using Node.js and React. My server is on PORT 5000 and my client is on PORT 3000. I want to integrate Google authentication using Auth0 in Node.js and integrate it to frontend. Can you provide the steps to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide what did you look for and, if you already found some documentation, what you find unclear about it

Comment: Thanks for replying @L_Cleo ! I am looking to integrate Auth0 to my full stack MERN project where my client is hosted on 3000 PORT & server on 5000 PORT. However, this one [link](https://community.auth0.com/t/cors-problem-using-express-create-react-app-auth0/36264) says I can't do that. I need to have client under my server.